# writing psycopg2 query result to pyspark dataframe

Tags: postgresql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there a way to directly fetch the contents of a table from a postgresQL database into a pyspark dataframe using the psycopg2 library?

The solutions online so far only talk about using a pandas dataframe. But that is not possible with very large set of data in spark since it would be loading all the data to the driver node.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(database="databasename", user='user', password='pass', host='postgres.host, port= '5432'
)

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from database.table limit 10")
data = cur.fetchall()
```

The resulting `data` output is a tuple that is difficult to convert to a dataframe.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `psycopg2` has other cursor factories available [Cursor factory](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#connection-and-cursor-subclasses), so you can return something other then a tuple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly use spark jdbc to connect to postgresql to read the data, and it will return a dataframe.

Comment: I have the following drivers installed in my EMR cluster:
`postgresql-42.2.12.jar`
`spark-avro_2.11-2.4.5.jar`
Would these enable spark to connect to postgres?

Comment: Yes.Put the jars in the spark classpath(E.g: $SPARK_HOME/jars) to use. Note the compatibility of the postgresql jdbc version with the server version.